# Ubuntu 17.04 nvidia-settings, how to run from sshd?

Tags: nvidia, ssh

I have a simple script, with GPU settings:

```
#!/bin/bash
#nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/GPUGraphicsMemoryOffset[3]=850'
nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=1900'
nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1'
nvidia-settings -a '[fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=80'
```

But I can't run this script over `ssh` or using crontab. These settings work only from actual screen/monitor.

When I am running it remotely, I get those errors:

```
$ ./gpu0.sh
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score -2):

Run this first:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```